# expect output truncated to 80 characters

Tags: linux, shell, console, expect, powerpc

I am writing some expect scripts for a target board running:

```
cat /proc/version
```

> Linux version 2.6.34.13-7_WR4.3_rsysadsp1 (root@bld1-sz.radisys.com)
>       (gcc version 4.4.1 (Wind River Linux Sourcery G++ 4.4a-341) ) #1
>       PREEMPT Fri Sep 5 21:55:02 EDT 2014

My problem is that the target's console is somehow limited to 80chars. If I call:

```
send "echo short command > /dev/null\r"
expect -ex $prompt
```

The output is:

```
echo short command > /dev/null
```

However, if I call:

```
send "echo lo-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-ong command > /dev/null \r"
```

The output goes insane:

```
v/null -o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-oong command > /de
```

It is obviously not related to expect. When trying to write a long string in the target's console, it looks like:
http://youtu.be/Zw-wJNSReUM

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What process are you interacting with? Is it your shell? What is your shell?

Comment: Host machine: GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu). Target board: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (powerpc-wrs-linux-gnu)

Comment: If you're connecting to a serial console, they generally only support 80x25 screen size (possibly 24, memory's a tad fuzzy on that) because it's emulating a physical screen, and not a virtual terminal.

Comment: You appear to be observing the effects of line-wrap...

Comment: Hey guys, appreciate your feedback a lot! So, is there really no way to get rid of this behavior, except by switching from serial to ssh connection?